# Запятая между повторяющимся союзом И и ИЛИ

Tags: и, или

Я часто теряюсь при расстановке знаков препинания в подобных предложениях. Пожалуйста, подскажите, какие правила помогут запомнить процесс лучше.

Предложение:

*- Подскажите, перепутали блюда и привезли вам салат вместо чего-то ещё или же просто дали лишний продукт?*

Что мы имеем:

- однородные члены предложения: перепутали, привезли, дали

Значит, перед И мы запятую не ставим. Но ставим ли мы её перед ИЛИ?

Разберём:

- это однородные придаточные, которые отвечают на один вопрос "что сделали?"
  Подскажите, что сделали: перепутали блюда, привезли салат вместо чего-то, дали лишний продукт.

Получается, запятая не нужна?

Comment: Здесь нет повторяющихся союзов.

Comment: Запятую лучше заменить на двоеточие. Она в этом случае не кстати.

Comment: Мне нужно верно поставить знаки, а не заменять их)

Comment: А в чём разница? Вы сами ставите двоеточие ниже.

Comment: Вы себе противоречите: то однородные члены, то придаточные. У придаточных должен быть подчинительный союз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, потому что там одно подлежащее (оно подразумевается) и однородные сказуемые:
*Подскажите: [они] перепутали блюда и привезли вам салат вместо чего-то ещё или же просто дали лишний продукт?*

При двоеточии звучит гораздо культурнее, а с запятой — разговорный вариант, оно не соответствует стилю. Слово "ещё" тоже не соответствует стилю.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Так стало понятнее :)